# Jenkins: how to pass a variable for a group of computers from environment injection

Tags: powershell, jenkins, environment-variables, invoke-command

I use Jenkins on Windows. I have a problem with passing variables from plugin "Environment Injector" to Powershell. Environment variables must contain a group record of computers, and I want to pass this variable in `Invoke-Command` as the "-Computers" parameter, but I'm getting this error:

> Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.
>   At C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins8257233376729955454.ps1:8 char:1
>   + Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:Web_Servers -Credential $Cred -Scri ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand`

PowerShell command:

```
$User = ".\user"
$Password = $env:user | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User,$Password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:Web_Servers -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Host}
```

Environment variable:

```
Web_Servers={172.16.250.126, 172.16.250.127}
```

Inject environment variables to the build process from "Properties File Path"

Comment: `$env:Web_Servers` -> `($env:Web_Servers -split '\s*,\s*')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your decision helped. One small clarification: what you need "\s*", if you just make commas as a separator?

Comment: You're example `172.16.250.126, 172.16.250.127` <-- clearly has a trailing space after the comma, thought I'd better give the "safe" version :)